# grep -f forEXACT pattern

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I want TO extract list of names from other bigger file (input), having that name and some additional information associated with that name. My problem is with grep -f option, as it is not matching the exact entries in input file but some other entries that contain similar name.

I tried:

```
$ grep -f list.txt -A 1 input >output
```

Following are the format of files;

list.txt

```
TE_final_35005
TE_final_1040
```

Input file

```
>TE_final_10401
ACGTACGTACGTACGT
>TE_final_35005 
ACGTACGATCAGT
>TE_final_1040
ACGTACGTACGT
```

Required output:

```
>TE_final_35005 
ACGTACGATCAGT
>TE_final_1040
ACGTACGTACGT
```

output I am getting:

```
>TE_final_10401
ACGTACGTACGTACGT
>TE_final_35005 
ACGTACGATCAGT
>TE_final_1040
ACGTACGTACGT
```

Although `TE_final_10401` is not in the list.txt

How I can use `^` in list?

Please help to match the exact value or suggest other ways to do this.

Comment: @Thor I wasn't sure if the spaces between the lines where intentional or not?

Comment: @sudo_O: the format looks very similar to [FASTA](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format), which generally isn't double spaced.

Answer (score 2):

Add the whole word switch (`-w`):

```
grep -w -A1 -f list.txt infile
```

Output:

```
>TE_final_35005 
ACGTACGATCAGT
>TE_final_1040
ACGTACGTACGT
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things, remove the blanks lines from the files first:

```
sed  -i '/^\s*$/d' file list
```

Then `-w` is used to match whole words only and `-A1` will print the next line after the match:

```
$ grep -w -A1 -f list file > new_file

$ cat new_file
>TE_final_35005
ACGTACGATCAGT
>TE_final_1040
ACGTACGTACGT
```

Answer (score 1):

as others have mentioned, adding the `-w` flag is the cleanest and easiest approach based on your sample data.  but since you explicitly asked how you could use `^` in `list.txt`, here's another option.

to add `^` and/or `$` anchors to each line in `list.txt`:

```
$ cat list.txt
^>TE_final_35005[ ]*$
^>TE_final_1040[ ]*$
```

this searches for your patterns at the start of the line, preceded by a `>` character, and ignores any trailing spaces.  then your previous command will work (assuming you either remove those blank lines or change your argument to `-A 2`).

if you'd like to add these anchors to the list file automatically (and delete any blank lines at the same time), use this `awk` construct:

```
awk '{if($0 != ""){print "^>"$0"[ ]*$"}}' list.txt >newlist.txt
```

or if you prefer `sed` inplace editing:

```
sed -i '/^[ ]*$/d;s/\(.*\)/^>\1[ ]*$/g' list.txt
```